# Как на Flex сделать две колонки с одинаковым количеством блоков и их размерами в каждой, если текст в этих блоках может быть разный

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, grid

Подскажите пожалуйста, как на Flex сделать две колонки, чтобы соседние по горизонтали блоки в ней были одинакового размера, независимо от длины текста в них.

Сейчас получается так, что они могут быть разной высота и нарушается структура.
[image: Как сейчас]

Хотелось бы добиться, вот такого результата:
[image: Как должно быть]

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, ваш текущий HTML и CSS, без них сделать ответ для вас, невозможно.

Comment: Grid бы идеально подошел

Answer (score 0):

У самих карточек с белым фоном задай css `height: 100%`